# core.mjs:10144 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOfOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

I faced ngfor problem and I solved this problem by adding library

app.module.ts folder

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the above problem

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
```

Including the `formsModule` library here fixed the issue

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
   CategoryComponent, 
    ProductComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```